# Determine whether Activity was closed or re-drawn

Tags: android

When using the onPause method in the Android SDK, that code is run whenever the Activity was re-drawn (Such as rotating the device). Is there a way to detect whether the Activity was actually paused (Such as a new window popping up) or if the Activity was actually just re-drawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you look at the life cycle of an activity, when the device is rotated, the activity is restarted, so after `onPause()`, the activity goes through the complete restart cycle (`onStop()` and `onRestart()` are also called), so in this case you can set some value depending on what functions were called, or check the device's orientation.

Also when the activity goes into background, `onPause()` is called, and when the activity is no longer visible to the user, `onStop()` is called, which are due to specific reasons, the application can check that by setting some variable. For complete understanding, study the [activity life cycle](http://grail.cba.csuohio.edu/~matos/notes/cis-493/lecture-notes/Android-Chapter03-Life-Cycle.pdf) ([Alternate Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html))

But why do you need to know what happened to the activity? By overriding appropriate functions and providing proper layout resources, you do not need to know what happened in most cases.

For orientation, you can also get the orientation using `getRotation` method.

Comment: Thank you providing such an awesome answer :) I'm a new Android Developer and I just didn't want people saying "Look it up" or "Look through some docs". If I had 15 Rep points I'd vote it up (Honestly I think I should be able to vote up answers to my questions but okay...), I've marked it as the answer though. That Activity Lifecycle resource is great too. Added to bookmarks :)

Comment: You are welcome, but exploring things is how one learns best, and you should not avoid searching for the answer and reading things by yourself because this way you'll learn more! Even I have given links which contain much more information than the answer, do read them!

Comment: Well, the problem for me wasn't not searching, I just had a hard time trying to think what to search. I really thank you for the links and I hope to be a better Android Developer :)